# Engine reversing water to the over flow container

Tags: cooling-system, radiator, pontiac, overheating, montana

I have a 1999 Pontiac Montana Van. The radiator fluid is backing up to the over flow container.

So,what can be my problem?

I put new thermostat in and flushed the radiator.

Are there any additional troubleshooting steps I can enact to discover what the problem is?

Comment: It could be the radiator cap. These are pressure rated (16 psi in your case) and when they get worn they can allow it to overheat and/or bypass to the overflow. This is a cheap troubleshooting items since they are usually under $10 and can solve a lot of cooling issues.

Comment: @CharlieRB - I'd put my $10 on a radiator cap first as well. A heck of a lot cheaper than jumping right to a leak/blown gasket. Good call.

Answer (score 2):

More than likely it is a head gasket leaking or a cracked cylinder head.

You can use a combustion leak detector to find out if it is the exhaust gases leaking into the cooling system causing your issue.

[https://www.amazon.com/Lisle-75500-Combustion-Leak-Detector/dp/B0007ZDRUI](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007ZDRUI)